# Moshi create json with dynamic inner data class

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2, moshi

I have moshi with retrofit and I want to send dynamic inner data object to backend.

Lets say I need to patch some data on my endpoint:

```kotlin
@PATCH("/animals/{animalId}/attributes")
suspend fun updateAnimal(@Path("animalId") animalId: String, @Body request: MyPetsRequest)
```

But my `AnimalAttributes` inner object is dynamic.

```kotlin
@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
@Parcelize
data class MyPetsRequest(
    @Json(name = "name") val name: String,
    @Json(name = "attributes") val attributes: AnimalAttributes
) : Parcelable

interface AnimalAttributes : Parcelable // or sealed class possible when share same base fields

@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
@Parcelize
data class DogAttributes(
    @Json(name = "bark") val bark: Boolean,
    @Json(name = "bite") val bite: Boolean,
) : AnimalAttributes

@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
@Parcelize
data class CatAttributes(
    @Json(name = "weight") val weight: Int,
) : AnimalAttributes
```

I tried create a custom adapter for Moshi, but when I use `@ToJson` inner object `attributes` data are escaped (so complete object is send as one parameter).

```kotlin
class AnimalAttributesAdapter {

    @ToJson
    fun toJson(value: AnimalAttributes): String {
        val moshi = Moshi.Builder().build()
        return when (value) {
            is DogAttributes -> moshi.adapter(DogAttributes::class.java).toJson(value)
            is CatAttributes -> moshi.adapter(CatAttributes::class.java).toJson(value)
            else -> throw UnsupportedOperationException("Unknown type to serialize object to json: $value")
        }
    }

    /**
     * Not supported, this object is used only one way to update data on server.
     */
    @FromJson
    fun fromJson(value: String): AnimalAttributes = throw UnsupportedOperationException()
}

Moshi.Builder().add(AnimalAttributesAdapter())
```

**Result in this case looks like:**
`{"name":"my pet name","attributes":"{\"bark\":\"true\", \"bite\":\"false\"}"}`

When I try to use `PolymorphicJsonAdapterFactory` it added next parameter between attributes which is not acceptable for my use case.

```kotlin
PolymorphicJsonAdapterFactory.of(AnimalAttributes::class.java, "animal")
            .withSubtype(DogAttributes::class.java, "dog")
            .withSubtype(CatAttributes::class.java, "cat")
```

Result in this case added attribute `animal`: `{"name":"my pet name","attributes":{"animal":"dog","bark":true, "bite":false}}`

I don't need to deserialize object from json to data class. I only need create one way serialization to json.